# Using pyautogui.typewrite() w/ special characters

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('Março')
```

It types Maro (it skips the character 'ç').

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this is use pyperclip like this.

```
def type_unicode(text):
    import pyautogui
    import pyperclip
    pyperclip.copy(text)
    pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "v")


type_unicode("Março")
```

if you are using Linux and doesn't work you may need to install these dependencies.

Debian
`sudo apt-get install xclip`

Arch
`sudo pacman -S xclip`

Original Articles:

https://intellipaat.com/community/8484/python-automagica-unicode-text

https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/